# Gaussian Process Kernel and Ridge Regression

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, ridge-regression

Can a Dual Ridge Regression produce the same prediction results as a Gaussian Process with a polynomial kernel $K(x,x')=(x^Tx'+1)^2$ in less time complexity (GP is $O(n^3)$ ) using Cholesky decomposition?

If yes what would the complexity of the Ridge Regression be with a kernel that produces the same results?

If not would an SVM model be suggested?

I want to achieve linear to the number features time complexity.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. If you want, you can delete your question by clicking the gray 'delete' under the tags.

Comment: Actually, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think he can now that he's got an upvoted answer...

Comment: Your question has an answer, so you don't really 'own' it any more - it contains work by other people (an answer) and you don't get to delete their effort without a very good reason. If there *is* an especially good reason, you should flag it instead and explain it to the moderators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cholesky decomposition also has a complexity of $O(n^3)$ operations, so it has the same computational scaling properties as Gaussian Process regression.  If you want to reduce time complexity, you could investigate a sparse approximation of the least-squares support vector machine (LSSVM) which is equivalent to dual ridge regression, which I have found useful, see e.g.

Gavin C Cawley and Nicola LC Talbot, "Improved sparse least-squares support vector machines", Neurocomputing, volume 48, number 1, pages 1025-1031, 2002

and

Gavin C. Cawley and Nicola LC Talbot, "A greedy training algorithm for sparse least-squares support vector machines", International Conference on Artificial Neural Networks—ICANN 2002, pages 681 686, 2002

If greedy selection of representation vectors is too slow, simply picking a subset of the data at random tends to work quite well (as long as all of the training data appear in the loss function).

I am not very keen on support vector regression as the $\epsilon$-insensitive loss function doesn't have a straightforward probabilistic interpretation, which is often important in regression applications.

Comment: use the same kernel as the covariance function of the GP, there is also a need to choose a suitable regularisation parameter for the KRR model to match the GP.

Comment: thanks I ll give it a try with theano and python! How would somebody chose the regularisation parameter? Bayesian optimisation until it fits?

Comment: @papajohn typically through cross-validation.

Comment: CV Makes sense... but my objective is to simulate the GP so how would the choice be done in that case?

Comment: I use leave-one-out cross-validation for setting the regularisation parameter of ridge regression models, which can be performed very cheaply (see         http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.neunet.2007.05.005 ).  However, IIRC, the regularisation parameter for ridge regression typically corresponds to a parameter of the covariance function of the GP, however the exact relationship depends on how it is coded.

Comment: Good answer (+1) but can you comment a bit further on how coding affects the relation? Why isn't the $K = K+\lambda I$-like  the "universal relation behind this regularization idea? Unless we are talking about a Generalized Tikhonov regularization scheme (which OK, it is a superset of ridge regression) I can't see why coding would be an issue. (If this happens to be a long answer feel free to point me to papers)